# Slicing a list in Python

Tags: python, list, matrix, slice

### EDIT.

Sorry, I should have been more clear. I add the entire function. This is to calculate the determinant of a matrix using recursion.

I'm trying to remove a middle column from a matrix.
My matrix:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I already removed the first row so left with:

```
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

My code where focus_col is the column I'm removing (height == 2)

```
def determinant(self, total = 0):
    indices = list(range(len(self.M)))  # indices of number of rows and number of columns (square matrix)

    if self.rows == 2 and self.columns == 2:
        return self.M[0][0] * self.M[1][1] - self.M[0][1] * self.M[1][0]

    for focus_col in indices:
        sub_m = Matrix(self.rows, self.columns)  # create sub matrix
        sub_m = self.M  # copy the matrix
        sub_m = sub_m[1:]  # remove the first row
        height = len(sub_m)

        # for each sub-matrix remove the focus column
        print(height)
        for i in range(height):

            print("before:  ", sub_m)
            sub_m[i] = sub_m[i][0:focus_col] + sub_m[i][focus_col + 1:]
            print("after:  ", sub_m)
```

My expected output:

```
5 6
8 9
```

or

```
before:   [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
after:   [[5, 6], [8, 9]]
```

My actual output:

```
5 6
7 8 9
```

or

```
before:   [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
after:   [[5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Each round the column I'm removing is different.
Anyone can tell me why in the second round when i == 1 it is not removing the 7?

Comment: are we assuming that sub_m equals your matrix ?

Comment: in other words, what is `sub_m` 's value ?  the matrix without the first row ?

Comment: Yes, sub_m equals the matrix before I remove the first row.

[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

Answer (score 0):

I made a couple of assumptions, but since you're overwriting the list, and using an additional variable, it got confusing. 
Using your code, I modify your line to simply overwrite and eliminate the first item of the list in which you're iterating.

```
sub_m = [ [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]  //asumption
for i in range(height):
    sub_m[i] = sub_m[i][1:]
```

Comment: Sorry, I added the rest of the code. Every run of the outer for loop the column I'm removing is different.

Answer (score 0):

Slice each sub list in the list of lists with a comprehension:

```
matrix=[[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]] 
nm=[sa[1:] for sa in matrix]

>>> nm
[[5, 6], [8, 9]]
```

Comment: Sorry, I added the rest of the code. Every run of the outer for loop the column I'm removing is different.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer solution of @dawg but with some improve to make it more dynamically, but you have to ensure that size of your matrix is same length on each row.

```
matrix=[[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]] 
nm=[sa for sa in list(matrix) if sa.pop(0)] # change pop index to index of element that you want to remove

>>> nm
[[5, 6], [8, 9]]
```

Comment: Sorry, I added the rest of the code. Every run of the outer for loop the column I'm removing is different.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solved it. 
I had to take it out of the Matrix class (class method) to its own function.